# How to evaluate $ \int \frac{x_{1}+x_{2} \sin \left(\frac{\pi z}{L}\right)}{x_{3}+x_{4} \sin \left(\frac{\pi z}{L}\right)} d z $

Tags: integration

I am stuck with the following integral,
$$
\int \frac{x_{1}+x_{2} \sin \left(\frac{\pi z}{L}\right)}{x_{3}+x_{4} \sin \left(\frac{\pi z}{L}\right)} d z
$$

^came up with this when I was trying to solve the two-phase pressure drop due to gravity inside a boiling water reactor. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Entering `integrate (x1+x2*sin(c*z))/(x3+x4*sin(c*z))` into wolframalpha.com may help in the loosest possible sense of the word "help"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Rewrite the integrand as
$$\frac{x_{1}+x_{2} \sin t}{x_{3}+x_{4} \sin t} 
=\frac{x_2}{x_4}+\left(\frac{x_1}{x_3} -\frac{x_2}{x_4}\right)
\frac1{1+ \frac{x_4}{x_3}\sin t}
$$

Comment: that did it! easy-peasy. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The integrand can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{a+b \sin x}{c+d \sin x} &=\int \frac{\frac{b}{d}(c+d \sin x)+a-\frac{b c}{d}}{c+d \sin x} d x \\
&=\frac{b}{d} \int 1 d x+\frac{a d-b c}{d} \int \frac{d x}{c+d \sin x} \\
&=\frac{b x}{d}+\frac{a d-b c}{d} \int \frac{d x}{c+d \sin x}
\end{aligned}
$$
where the last integral can be found by Weiertrass substitution.